Icon in app catalog for an SPFx(1.19) based application
I have built an app using SPFx 1.19 and there is an issue with an App when it gets uploaded in App Catalog.
The icon for this app in App-Catalog is broken icon. It doesn't pick-up the icon which i set as "iconPath" in package json file.
The problem behind it is-when the app is getting uploaded then the clientSideAssets folder contains the hashed name of this icon. Due to which it is not showing the intended icon.
Is there any way to resolve this. So far, I came across the solution which is- Admin has to manually modify the icon url or manually upload the icon to clientSideAssets folder.
Thanks in advance.

You can use Base64 format in iconImageUrl property - no need to worry about storage and access.

